# Waitgroups and synchronization not working in Go

Tags: go, concurrency

I've been experimenting with goroutines and channels, and I wanted to test the WaitGroup feature. Here I'm trying to execute an HTTP flood job, where the parent thread spawns a lot of goroutines which will make infinite requests, unless receiving a stop message:

```
func (hf *HTTPFlood) Run() {
childrenStop := make(chan int, hf.ConcurrentCalls)
stop := false

totalRequests := 0
requestsChan := make(chan int)
totalErrors := 0
errorsChan := make(chan int)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i < hf.ConcurrentCalls; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            select {
            case <-childrenStop:
                fmt.Printf("stop child\n")
                return
            default:
                _, err := Request(hf.Victim.String())
                requestsChan <- 1
                if err != nil {
                    errorsChan <- 1
                }
            }
        }
    }()
}
timeout := time.NewTimer(time.Duration(MaximumJobTime) * time.Second)
for !stop {
    select {
    case req := <- requestsChan:
        totalReq += req
    case err := <- errorsChan:
        totalErrors += err
    case <- timeout.C:
        fmt.Printf("%s timed up\n", hf.Victim.String())
        for i := 0; i < hf.ConcurrentCalls; i++ {
            childrenStop <- 1
        }
        close(childrenStop)
        stop = true
        break
    }
}
fmt.Printf("waiting\n")
wg.Wait()
fmt.Printf("after wait\n")
close(requestsChan)
close(errorsChan)
fmt.Printf("end\n")
}
```

Once timeout is fired, the parent thread successfully exits the loop and reaches the Wait instruction, but even though the stopChildren channel is filled, the child goroutines seem to never receive messages on the stopChildren channel.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

So the issue obviously was how the channels and its sends/receives were managed.
First of all the childrenStop channel was closed before all childs had received the message. The channel should be closed after the Wait

On the other hand, since no reads were done neither on requestsChan nor errorsChan once the parent thread sends the stop signal, most of the childs stayed blocked sending on these two channels. I tried to keep reading in the parent thread, outside the loop just before the Wait but that didn't work so I switched the implementation to Atomic counters which seem to be a more suitable way to manage this specific use case.

```
func (hf *HTTPFlood) Run() {
childrenStop := make(chan int, hf.ConcurrentCalls)

var totalReq uint64
var totalErrors uint64

var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i < hf.ConcurrentCalls; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            select {
            case <-childrenStop:
                fmt.Printf("stop child\n")
                return
            default:
                _, err := Request(hf.Victim.String())
                atomic.AddUint64(&totalReq, 1)
                if err != nil {
                    atomic.AddUint64(&totalErrors, 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }()
}
timeout := time.NewTimer(time.Duration(MaximumJobTime) * time.Second)

<- timeout.C
fmt.Printf("%s timed up\n", hf.Victim.String())
for i := 0; i < hf.ConcurrentCalls; i++ {
    childrenStop <- 1
}
fmt.Printf("waiting\n")
wg.Wait()
fmt.Printf("after wait\n")
close(childrenStop)
fmt.Printf("end\n")
```

}

Comment: You are closing the channel to soon. ```childrenStop``` is a buffered channel that means just because you fill the channel does not mean they will be read. Try moving it after ```wg.Wait()```. I believe that should work.

Comment: will try, thank you

Comment: @praveent if you close a buffered channel, readers will still receive what's in the buffer until it is emptied. Closing the channel doesn't stop the already-buffered messages from being read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your go routines can be is blocked at `requestsChan <- 1`.

```
case <- timeout.C:
        fmt.Printf("%s timed up\n", hf.Victim.String())
        for i := 0; i < hf.ConcurrentCalls; i++ {
            childrenStop <- 1
        }
        close(childrenStop)
        stop = true
        break
```

Here you are sending a number to `childrenStop` and expect the go routines to receive it. But while you are sending the childrenStop signal, your routines could have sent something on `requestsChan`. But as you break from the loop after sending the close signals, there's no one listening on `requestsChan` to receive.

You can confirm this by printing something just before and after `requestsChan <- 1` to confirm the behaviour.

**A channel will block when you send something on it while no one is receiving on the other end**

Here is a possible modification.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    requestsChan := make(chan int)

    done := make(chan chan bool)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func(it int) {
            for {
                select {
                case c := <-done:
                    c <- true
                    return
                default:
                    requestsChan <- it
                }
            }

        }(i)
    }

    max := time.NewTimer(1 * time.Millisecond)
    allChildrenDone := make(chan bool)
    childrenDone := 0
    childDone := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case i := <-requestsChan:
                fmt.Printf("received %d;", i)
            case <-max.C:
                fmt.Println("\nTimeup")
                for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
                    go func() {
                        done <- childDone
                        fmt.Println("sent done")
                    }()
                }
            case <-childDone:
                childrenDone++
                fmt.Println("child done ", childrenDone)
                if childrenDone == 5 {
                    allChildrenDone <- true
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("Waiting")
    <-allChildrenDone
}
```

Thing to note here is that am sending the close signal in go routines so that the loop can continue while i wait for all the children to have cleanly exit.

Please watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs) talk by Rob Pike which covers these details clearly.

[Edit]: The previous code would have resulted in a running routine after exiting.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it helped me understand a bit more about channel operations and what blocks execution and what not. I've managed to make some changes in order to fix the behaviour

Comment: Great. Mark the answer as a solution if it helped you. Thanks.